# row insertion in html table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I created this html form.

```
<form id="formu">
    <label for="n" >First Name : </label><input type="text" id="n"/><br/>
    <label for="p" >Last Name : </label><input type="text" id="p"/><br/>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

when the form is submitted, i want to add informations provided by the user to a table. the table code is :

```
<table id="tab" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>First Name</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

this is the javascript code for the form submission

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var fo = document.getElementById("formu");


        fo.addEventListener("submit",function()
        {
            var tab=document.getElementById("tab");

            var lign = tab.insertRow();

            var id1 = lign.insertCell(0);

            var nom = lign.insertCell(1);

            var prenom = lign.insertCell(2);

            id1.innerHTML="1";
            nom.innerHTML=document.getElementById("n").value;
            prenom.innerHTML=document.getElementById("p").value;

        });

</script>
```

but once the form is submitted, the submited data appear in the tbale and disapear just after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the data is disappearing is that by using a standard form the page will refresh as the form is submitted to itself.

To prevent this, you need to use `preventDefault()` in your function, for example:

```
fo.addEventListener("submit",function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab=document.getElementById("tab");

        var lign = tab.insertRow();

        var id1 = lign.insertCell(0);

        var nom = lign.insertCell(1);

        var prenom = lign.insertCell(2);

        id1.innerHTML="1";
        nom.innerHTML=document.getElementById("n").value;
        prenom.innerHTML=document.getElementById("p").value;

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The form submits when you press the submit button, so it effectively refreshes the form, you could add onsubmit="return false;" to the form tag for a quick fix

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Insert a row in the table at the last row
var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

// Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

// Append a text node to the cell
var newText  = document.createTextNode('New row');
newCell.appendChild(newText);
```